# Negative test automation Commands in Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I need to know where can I find negative methods list for selenium / Java. For example, I just learned about  `.reverseString()`  which allows us to use a login name spelled backward **(password - drowssap)**.  I'm looking for other methods similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the concept of Selenium wrong.

Selenium does not provide any tool-set for any kind of test data management. Selenium just provides utility to interact with UI elements. It is up to you how you design negative tests and how you prepare the data you'll be using for interaction.